# Image overflows stroke inside SVG shape

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, svg

In my React app, I want to be able to crop an image and embed it into a hexagonal SVG shape to use as an avatar. I've done the cropping part and made the SVG border, just one problem that I have is that the embedded picture overflows the border approximately to its half and I want that border to be fully visible.
Here is my code:

```
export const HexagonFrame = ({ logo }) => {
  return (
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      width="63.191"
      height="69.06"
      viewBox="0 0 63.191 69.06"
    >
      <defs>
        <clipPath id="shape">
          <path
            id="hex"
            d="M4.2,34.351c.161-3.452.08-6.825.482-10.277A13.043,13.043,0,0,1,11.025,14.2c4.416-2.81,8.993-5.379,13.489-8.029,4.978-2.971,9.956-2.81,14.854.08C43.382,8.659,47.4,11.068,51.412,13.4c4.737,2.81,7.547,6.9,7.708,12.445.161,6.182.08,12.445-.241,18.627a12.05,12.05,0,0,1-5.54,9.474c-5.058,3.292-10.277,6.423-15.577,9.394a12.22,12.22,0,0,1-12.285-.08c-4.9-2.73-9.635-5.62-14.372-8.591-4.577-2.89-6.664-7.226-6.825-12.525-.08-2.569,0-5.138,0-7.788Z"
            transform="translate(-0.01 0.042)"
            fill="none"
            stroke="#fff"
            strokeMiterlimit="10"
            strokeWidth="8"
            strokeOpacity="1"
          />
        </clipPath>
      </defs>
      <use xlinkHref="#hex" />
      {logo && (
        <image
          width="63.191"
          height="69.06"
          clipPath="url(#shape)"
          xlinkHref={logo}
          id="logo"
        />
      )}
    </svg>
  );
};
```

And screenshots of the hexagonal shape I'm working with. As you can see the border is overflown by the picture inside

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must position the stroke in front of the image.

SVG strokes are positioned onto the middle of the path they are defined with. So if you just change the order, part of the image will be obscured by the stroke. To avoid that, you need to reposition (by 4px, half the width of the stroke) and resize (by 8px, the full width of the stroke) the image. Like this:

```
export const HexagonFrame = ({ logo }) => {
  return (
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      width="63.191"
      height="69.06"
      viewBox="0 0 63.191 69.06"
    >
      <defs>
        <clipPath id="shape">
          <path
            id="hex"
            d="M4.2,34.351c.161-3.452.08-6.825.482-10.277A13.043,13.043,0,0,1,11.025,14.2c4.416-2.81,8.993-5.379,13.489-8.029,4.978-2.971,9.956-2.81,14.854.08C43.382,8.659,47.4,11.068,51.412,13.4c4.737,2.81,7.547,6.9,7.708,12.445.161,6.182.08,12.445-.241,18.627a12.05,12.05,0,0,1-5.54,9.474c-5.058,3.292-10.277,6.423-15.577,9.394a12.22,12.22,0,0,1-12.285-.08c-4.9-2.73-9.635-5.62-14.372-8.591-4.577-2.89-6.664-7.226-6.825-12.525-.08-2.569,0-5.138,0-7.788Z"
            transform="translate(-0.01 0.042)"
            fill="none"
            stroke="#fff"
            strokeMiterlimit="10"
            strokeWidth="8"
            strokeOpacity="1"
          />
        </clipPath>
      </defs>
      {logo && (
        <image
          x="4"
          y="4"
          width="55.191"
          height="61.06"
          clipPath="url(#shape)"
          xlinkHref={logo}
          id="logo"
        />
      )}
      <use xlinkHref="#hex" />
    </svg>
  );
};
```